# SQL Server 2005 XML with Namespaces

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, xquery, xml-namespaces

Sorry for the kind of n00b question, but this is my first time dealing with XML in SQL Server (2005).  Here is what I thought would work...

```
DECLARE @doc xml

SET @doc =

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:OrderRequest xmlns:p="http://xxx.OrderRequest/2" xmlns:xsi="http://xxx.XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xxx.OrderRequestV2.xsd ">
  <p:Header>
    <p:LLLRequestCount>0</p:LLLRequestCount>
    <p:MFRRequestCount>1</p:MFRRequestCount>
    <p:FileCreatedAt>2001-12-31T12:00:00</p:FileCreatedAt>
    <p:RequestFileName>p:RequestFileName</p:RequestFileName>
  </p:Header>
  <p:RequestItems>
  <p:MFRRequest id="1" priority="">
      <p:AccountNumber>9999999</p:AccountNumber>
      <Status>Initial</Status>
      <p:CaseInformation>
       <ReferralDate>2011-01-01</ReferralDate>
       <Type>1A</Type>
       <ARM>Yes</ARM>
        <InvestorNumber>InvestorNumber</InvestorNumber>
        <PropertyAddress>PropertyAddress</PropertyAddress>
        <PrivateLabel>Yes</PrivateLabel>
        <CaseNumber>01-11111/AK/</CaseNumber>
        <SuspenseBalance>9999.00</SuspenseBalance>
        <TitleOrderedDate>2011-09-01</TitleOrderedDate>
        <TotalMonthlyPayment>876.99</TotalMonthlyPayment>
      </p:CaseInformation>
    </p:MFRRequest>
  </p:RequestItems>
</p:OrderRequest>'
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://xxx.OrderRequest/2)')


SELECT Y.i.value('Status[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS Status
FROM @doc.nodes('/OrderRequest/MFRRequest') AS Y(i)
```

... but I get back blank.  I have tried using OPENXML as well.  I only ever get blanks.  I've tried so many examples at this point and I am not sure what I'm missing :-/

I need to pull back the ID property of MFRRequest, AccountNumber, Status, and then several of the fields in CaseInformation.  I would be very grateful for any assistance.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1. you have the namespace incorrect - there's no closing bracket at the end; the namespace must be specified as `'http://xxx.OrderRequest/2'` (not `'http://xxx.OrderRequest/2)'`)
2. you missed one XML element between `<OrderRequest>` and `<MFRRequest>` - there's a `<RequestItems>` in between those two
3. some elements use the namespace - some (like `<Status>`) don't - so you need to use a XML namespace prefix for your namespace to indicate which elements use it (and which don't).

So if you use this T-SQL code instead - it will work:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://xxx.OrderRequest/2' AS p)
SELECT 
    Y.i.value('Status[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS Status
FROM 
    @doc.nodes('/p:OrderRequest/p:RequestItems/p:MFRRequest') AS Y(i)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I hate to ask another question on the same thread, but is there any way to pull data from multiple nodes?  I noticed that if I defined the node as '/p:OrderRequest/p:RequestItems/p:MFRRequest/p:CaseInformation' that Status and AccountNumber became NULL.  This seems to make sense.

I need to pull from MFRRequest as well as CaseInformation.  I also need to pull the property MFRRequest id="1".  Will this require 2 different queries and then I have to join the data back together?

Comment: I'm sorry I am still learning this site too haha and it won't let me post a response -- it only allows me to post comments now :-/

Comment: @meowmeow: sounds like enough to just ask a second question! :-) I'm pretty sure there's a way to do all this in a single query. Just ask - I'll be happy to answer! :-)